# Gap between MDF Skirting Board and Engineered Wood Floor

Tags: flooring, gap, engineered-flooring, skirting

I have engineered hardwood floor (2cm thick, 190cm x 19cm).
Flooring is installed using glue over both concrete and over plywood(?) subfloor.
I have MDF skirting boards. The skirtings come with white paint finish so I can't really paint over them.

The problem is that the subfloor wasn't even and in some places there are smaller/bigger gaps between the floor and skirting.

I was thinking how to best fix this issue. The ideal solution would be to cut skirting boards to shape of the floor but that is not possible now.

I was considering whether I could  use some sort of filler but it might be difficult to achieve the same finish.

Acrylic Caulk is too flexible and gets dirty.

This leaves silicone filler, but im not sure how that will look.

Any suggestions how do you solve those?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably want paintable  caulking to match the paint.

Comment: Unless there is a reason that the tiny gaps must be closed, they are usually left alone.  Acrylic caulk is commonly used if the gaps are to be filled.

Comment: Accept them. Examine systems similar to yours over the next couple of months as you're going about your business. You'll discover the same gaps.